# Read JSONP Response in Dev Environment :- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, response, uncaught-exception

In my  local m/c I am trying to validate the User by  passing his details to a Cross-domain Url. On browser Console Log  I get error 
 `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"` and when i click on it I get `{"response": "PASS"}.`

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    url: 'https://my.site.com/validation.xml',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    jsonp: false,
    data: {
        accountnumber: ActNumber                
    },
    timeout: 60000,
    success: accountValidationResponse,
    error: accountValidationError
});
```

```text
https://my.site.com/validation.xml'?callback=jQuery22409542193305264031_1483533842731&accountnumber=12345678&_=1483533842732
```

Changing the `dataType` to `json` gives me this error:

> No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Normally this occurs when people are trying to get around a CORS issue so just set JSONP as the response type. Are you 100% sure the response is in JSONP format? It's not interchangeable with JSON.

Comment: calling an XML resource and you expect to get JSONP back? Seems strange. You can not just request JSONP and get it to return, the service needs to understand that and handle it.

Comment: I added a real URL in Comments , does it wrong

Comment: I copied the Code from Other Site and implication in local. In the Original site this code having dataType: 'JSON'

Comment: That's not JSONP - that's JSON. Change `dataType: 'json'` and remove `jsonpCallback` and `jsonp` parameters.

Comment: Then i get "Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Comment: That's what I suspected in my first comment. This means that the domain you're calling does not include CORS headers in the response. In turn, you cannot make a request to the domain from JS code - you'll have to do it server side. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information